# Is there a more efficient way of counting instances of a string with treemaps?

Tags: java, treemap

So I got a treemap to which I add courses that come from a random generator, the names are consistent but the order is not. For example I got these:

```java
List course = new ArrayList();             
        course.add("COP2210");
        course.add("COP2250");
        course.add("ENC1250");
        course.add("MLP1337");
        course.add("ENC3250");
        course.add("REL2210");
        course.add("MUS3200");
        course.add("PHI1240");
        course.add("SOL5000");
        course.add("HAL9000");
```

Now that's ten courses in total, and while the code below works to count one of them it would mean i have to get about nine more int variables written and repeat the if statement another nine times, that would be undesirable. I should mention the treemap is inside a loop and resets everytime, which is something I want. but a second treemap can be made  outside the loop to add the courses, i got no issue with that. But it is entirely possible that some courses never even gets added to the treemap as they are randomly chosen from the ten above.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfStudents; ++i){

        order = RandomCourse();

        TreeMap<String, Integer> tmap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
        tmap.put(courses.get(order[0]).toString(), 0);
        tmap.put(courses.get(order[1]).toString(), 0);
        tmap.put(courses.get(order[2]).toString(), 0);


        String comparator1 = courses.get(order[0]).toString();
        String comparator2 = courses.get(order[1]).toString();
        String comparator3 = courses.get(order[2]).toString();

        if(comparator1 == "HAL9000" || comparator2 == "HAL9000" || comparator3 == "HAL9000")
        HAL9000students++;




        courses.indexOf(order[0]);

        //Clean variable
        SortedCourses = "";

        //Map logic
        Set set = tmap.entrySet();
        Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
         Map.Entry mentry = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
        SortedCourses = SortedCourses + mentry.getKey() + " ";

      }

        students.add(ID_Prefix + i+ ", " + student.get(i) + " " + SortedCourses);
                                                  }
```

Order is a int array of size 3. Where a random number is stored, it is then used to choose from courses list a position which corresponds to a course.

Comment: May not be the most efficient, but I'd make a for loop over the list, and collect the counts in HashMap

Comment: What are you even trying to achieve with that `TreeMap`? It doesn't make any sense. Are you trying to see whether `order[0]`, `order[1]`, and `order[2]` are all `"HAL9000"`? The TreeMap isn't helping you do that in any way whatsoever. Also, `==` isn't how you check string equality; you do that with `equals`.

Comment: @user2357112 why equals?

Comment: Because `==` tests for reference equality and `equals()` tests for object equailty.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please explain exactly what part of this story is the input, and what you are trying to do with that input. What's in `order`? What is `courses` and where are you using `course`? What's the loop they are inside?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Done, I edited to show more and explain. The input is the list of courses and selected based on a random number from 1 to 10.

Comment: 1. indent your code kthxbai, 2. variable names should start with lowercase letters (`NumberOfStudents`, `HAL9000students`, `SortedCourses`), 3. why do you assign the `courses.get(order[0]).toString()` things to a variable *after* already using them as treemap keys? and why do you call them comparators? they are no comparators, friend, and naming is important -- it's one of the two hardest things in computer science, 4. why do you use iterator? just do `for (Map.Entry entry : tmap.entrySet())`

Comment: Anyways, a tree map is not like the best available option for counting things. You may want to take a look at *bags* from commons-collections. Although I am not sure. Please refactor your code a bit (e.g. according to my previous comment) because right now it looks obfuscated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have a situation where you need to do the same sort of operation for a lot of different values, it should give you a hint not to use individual variables, but rather an array or a collection.

You want to get the number of students in each course. So instead of keeping a variable for every course (what happens if there are 15 courses? 100?), you can use a map from the course name to the number of students in that course.

In this case, since you are already dealing with the *indexes* of the courses rather than their name, you can actually do that with an array.

```
int[] studentCounts = new int[course.size()];
```

This will be, of course, declared outside the loop. In this array, `studentCounts[0]` will be the number of students in the course indexed 0 ("COP2210"). `studentCounts[1]` will be the number of students in course index 1 ("COP2250") and so on.

So, if your `order` array is, for example, `{3,5,9}`, then you'll need to increment `studentCounts[3]`, `studentCount[5]` and `studentCount[9]`:

```
for ( int courseIndex : order ) {
    studentCounts[courseIndex]++;
}
```

Your second issue is that you want to print the names of the courses selected for each student ordered alphabetically. You use a `TreeMap` for that, but there is no reason to use a map - you are not actually using the values of the map, just the keys. So a `TreeSet` is going to make more sense.

So if you declare

```
TreeSet<String> sortedCourseNames = new TreeSet<>();
```

You can add to it inside the loop above:

```
for ( int courseIndex : order ) {
    studentCounts[courseIndex]++;
    sortedCourseNames.add( course.get(courseIndex) );
}
```

A `Set` has a simpler iterator than a `Map`. You can get the strings directly:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(ID_PREFIX)
  .append(i)
  .append(',')
  .append(student.get(i))
  .append(' ');

for ( String courseName : sortedCourseNames ) {
    sb.append(courseName)
      .append(' ');
}

students.add( sb.toString() );
```

---

So, some notes:

- Java has coding conventions. Type names (class,interface,enum) should start with a capital letter (e.g. `BigPicture`). Method, variable and field names should start with a lowercase letter (e.g. `bigPicture`), and constants should be all-caps (e.g. `BIG_PICTURE`). So a variable name like `SortedCourses` is bad, and so is `HAL9000students` and `ID_prefix`. I assumed that the ID prefix is a constant (declared `static final String`), so `ID_PREFIX` is the correct name. But if it's a variable, it should be `idPrefix`.
- Do *not* use raw types. Never declare anything to be a `List`, `TreeMap`, etc., without using the base type. It has to be `List<String>`, `TreeMap<String,Integer>`, `Set<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>` and so on. Using generics properly is important for type safety, and it saves you casting. So don't ignore those warnings about "raw types" that the compiler gives you!
- In my solution, you don't need to compare strings. But if you need to compare strings, you do it by `str1.equals(str2)`, *not* `str1 == str2`.
- Don't use the operator `+` to concatenate strings in loops. It's good enough for something like `a = "foo " + b + "bar"` - a single string concatenation. But in a loop:

  ```
  String result = "";
  for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
      result = result + " something else ";
  }
  ```

  Too many objects are created and discarded. It's better to use a `StringBuilder` as I have shown.